# How do i order collections which are ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy and not saved to db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The class of `books` is Book::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy.

Those are not saved yet to data base.

`Book` has the attributes of `isbn` and `price`.

I want to order `books` by `isbn` and `price`.

so I tried to `books.order(:isbn, :price)`

this result is empty array([])

How do i order the collections which are not saved to database?

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Use the Enumerable#sort_by method

Comment: Thanks!
```books.order(:isbn, :price)``` returns empty array. the reason why is those list are not saved to db yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in memory sorting with `Array#sort` or `Array#sort_by`

```
books.sort_by { |b| [b.isbn, b.price]  }
```